# Extracting text with no tags/formatting in HTML file with Robobrowser, Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

```
<font color="white">
    <b>Name:</b> USERNAME [585743] <br>  
    <b>Money:</b> $MONEY <br>   
    <b>Location:</b> CITY<br>
    <b>Level:</b> 43<br>
    <b>Gold:</b> 4706 / 5315<br>
</font>
```

I have this HTML inside a messy page. I want to extract the elements between each `</b>` and `<br>`. They are pure text, and there is no useful class or ID I can use.

Code I've used so far:

```
browser.open(bank_url)

soup = browser.parsed


result2 = re.search(r'</b> (.*?)<br/>', src).group(0)
print(result2)
```

This resulted in

```
</b> USERNAME [585743] <br>
```

getting printed. That's a good start but for some reason I can't get any more of the elements to get printed?

Is there a way to just extract a specific piece of the text? for example the gold text 4706 / 5315 ?

I'm using robobrowser, beautifulsoup in python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

If you are using beautifulsoup you should first make the BeautifulSoup object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<font color="white">)
     <b>Name:</b> USERNAME [585743] <br>  
     <b>Money:</b> $MONEY <br>   
     <b>Location:</b> CITY<br>
     <b>Level:</b> 43<br>
     <b>Gold:</b> 4706 / 5315<br>
</font>''', 'html.parser')
```

Then you can parse the texts you need finding the `<b>` elements and getting their `next_sibling`:

```
>>> for i in soup.findAll('b'):
     print(i.next_sibling)

 USERNAME [585743] 
 $MONEY 
 CITY
 43
 4706 / 5315
```

Comment: I don't understand, the code chunk is a tiny chunk of a large site. My issue is I don't have a good way to tell beautifulsoup what to select. How do I tell it to select everything you copied there?

Comment: You could use the font tag, if you are sure the chunk is always inside it

Comment: I've tried the font tag but for some reason I have a lot of trouble doing over multiple lines. How do you do the font tag without using regex?

Answer (score 1):

Using [.next_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) you can get the value next to the `Gold:` out of the elements. This is how that approach looks like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

element = """
<font color="white">
    <b>Name:</b> USERNAME [585743] <br>  
    <b>Money:</b> $MONEY <br>   
    <b>Location:</b> CITY<br>
    <b>Level:</b> 43<br>
    <b>Gold:</b> 4706 / 5315<br>
</font>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(element,"lxml")
item = [elem.next_sibling.strip() for elem in soup.select("font b") if "Gold" in elem.text]
print(' '.join(item))
```

Output:

```
4706 / 5315
```

Comment: I guess you can directly use `soup.find('b', text='Gold:').next_sibling`.

Comment: Yep, I noticed it in the first place but the problem is: the elements OP pasted above is a scattered poortion of a big chunk. So, if there is another container having another tag name (other than `font`) holding `Gold:` as item then the code will give wrong result. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, yea the site is a complete mess with no div tags what so ever. it's just a bunch of <td> and <tr> and <table> with barely any classes. I'll try what you said. I have 1 more question, I use robobrowser to login to the site, will the soup.find stuff keep me logged in? I'm new to this. One issue I've been having is if I run html requests it fetches the logged out site.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` doesn't play any role in logging in procedure. It is one of the finest parsers available out there. It helps you get text out of the elements generated by any browser simulator or http requests. So it should not have any conflict with your log in thing.  Thanks.